# Subset a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [45, 67, 12, 78, 92, 65, 89, 12, 34, 78],
     "B": ["h", "b", "f", "d", "e", "t", "y", "p", "w", "q"],
     "C": [True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True]})
```

I would like to select 50% of the rows randomly, ensuring that column "C" is True in 90% of the selected rows and False in the remaining 10%. How can I achieve this?

Comment: your data only has 10 rows, so this isn't possible by subsetting. can you explain exactly how you want to achieve this? are you trying to randomly sample from the data, with replacement?

Comment: This is just for example, I have a lot of data and I want to select only 50% of them so that 10% of the selected data is False and 90% is True. @MichaelDelgado

Comment: Can you show us what you’ve tried? It seems like you have something specific in mind but I’m not really understanding what you’re trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Your original dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"A": [45, 67, 12, 78, 92, 65, 89, 12, 34, 78],
     "B": ["h", "b", "f", "d", "e", "t", "y", "p", "w", "q"],
     "C": [True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True]})

# Select 50% of the rows randomly
selected_rows = df.sample(frac=0.5, random_state=42)

# Determine the number of rows where C should be True and False in the selected subset
num_true = int(0.9 * len(selected_rows))
num_false = len(selected_rows) - num_true

# Update C column to meet the criteria for the selected subset
selected_rows.loc[selected_rows['C'].sample(n=num_false, random_state=42).index, 'C'] = False

# Output the resulting dataframe
print(selected_rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

- firstly create a dataframe in 1000 rows

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
           {"A":[45,67,12,78,92,65,89,12,34,78],
            "B":["h","b","f","d","e","t","y","p","w","q"],
            "C":[True,False,False,True,False,True,True,True,True,True]})
df = pd.concat([df]*100)
print(df)
```

- secondly get the `true_row_num` and `false_row_num`

```py
row_num, _ = df.shape
true_row_num = int(row_num * 0.5 * 0.9)
false_row_num = int(row_num * 0.5 * 0.1)
print(true_row_num, false_row_num)
```

- thirdly randomly sample true_df and false_df respectively

```py
true_df = df[df["C"]].sample(true_row_num)
false_df = df[~df["C"]].sample(false_row_num)
new_df = pd.concat([true_df, false_df])
new_df = new_df.sample(frac=1.0).reset_index(drop=True) # shuffle
print(new_df["C"].value_counts())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you calculate the needed sizes ex ante and then perform random sampling per group it might work. Look at something like this:

```
new=df.query('C==True').sample(int(0.5*len(df)*0.9)).append(df.query('C==False').sample(int(0.5*len(df)*0.1)))
```